# Get posts having meta value between two numbers

Tags: wp-query, meta-query

have a problem with `meta_query_args`.

```
<?php
$money_form = 0;
$money_form = $_POST['search_option_money'];

if( $money_form != 0 ){
    $meta_query_args =  array(
        array(
            'key'     => $money_form,
            'value'   => array(
                'offer_money_start',
                'offer_money_end'
            ),
            'type'    => 'decimal',
            'compare' => 'BETWEEN' ///BETWEEN
        ),
    );
} else {
    //
}

$myquery = new WP_Query( array(
    'post_type'      => 'mycredit',
    'posts_per_page' => -1,
    'orderby'        => 'rand',
    'meta_query'     => $meta_query_args
) );
```

I need all the offer which is between start and end, but I have no results. I don't know why?

All its ok thanks :)

Comment: Maybe I don't understand, but this seems backwards. You're asking the database to run a BETWEEN search with two strings. Are offer_money_start and end supposed to be ACF fields for this post? Please explain in more depth what you are trying to do.

Comment: offer_money_start and end is number

Comment: change `decimal` to `numeric`

Comment: Now i have all records and it's not working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question isn't clear, but I'm making the following assumptions:

1. The user is submitting `$_POST['search_option_money'];`
2. You want to return all `mycredit` posts where `$_POST['search_option_money'];` is between the `offer_money_start` and `offer_money_end` custom fields.

The problem is that you're misusing the `key` and `value` arguments of the meta query. The `key` is the name of the custom field, and `value` is the value you're searching for.

Also, the `BETWEEN` meta query is when you want to find posts based on a meta key's value being between 2 specified values, not for finding posts based on a value between 2 separate meta keys.

If you want to find posts where a given value is between the value of 2 separate meta keys, you need 2 separate meta queries:

```
$query_args = [
    'post_type'      => 'mycredit',
    'posts_per_page' => -1
    'orderby'        => 'rand',
];

if ( isset( $_POST['search_option_money'] ) ) {
    $money_form = $_POST['search_option_money'];

    $query_args['meta_query'] = [
        'relation' => 'AND',
        [
            'key'     => 'offer_money_start',
            'value'   => $money_form,
            'compare' => '>=',
            'type'    => 'DECIMAL',
        ],
        [
            'key'     => 'offer_money_end',
            'value'   => $money_form,
            'compare' => '<=',
            'type'    => 'DECIMAL',
        ],
    ]
}

$my_query = new WP_Query( $query_args );
```

This will query any posts where the submitted value from the form is greater than the `offer_money_start` custom field, but less than the `offer_money_end` custom field.

I've also formatted the code so that the meta query is properly set only when `$_POST['search_option_money']` exists. Your current code will assign `meta_query` to an undefined variable if it doesn't.

Lastly, POST requests are inappropriate for *getting* data, which is what searching or filtering is doing. Your form should be use the `GET` method, and `$_POST` should be `$_GET`.

Comment: Thank you all its work :)